# How to refer an input to a list, and then refer to the list using the inputted variable | PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, input, concatenation

How would I go about using a user input to refer to a list, and then continuing to use this user input to refer to the list.

For example:

```
list1 = [6,23,9]
list2 = ["book","tree","car"]
getlist = input("Enter list: ")
print(getlist[0])
```

This code will just print the first letter of the input, but how would I make it print the first index of the inputted list. For example if I input list2, how will I get the input 'book' rather than 'l'.
Many thanks.

Comment: `input` returns a `string` (which is why `getlist[0]` is just the first character); you'll need to convert that to a list.

Comment: So you are saying you want to input the *name* of the list you want?

Comment: If you want the user to be able to enter `list1` and `list2`, it would be better to store your data in a dictionary with keys `"list1"` and `"list2"`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no good way to map user input to actual variable names.

Use a dictionary instead, where the top-level keys are the list names.

```
data = {
    "list1": [6,23,9],
    "list2": ["book","tree","car"],
}

name = input("Enter list: ")
print(data[name][0])
```

Comment: Thanks - I had not heard of this before, going to have some interesting potential.

Comment: There is a *way*, if not so good: `globals()[name]`.